# Use base64_decode and base64_encode as per Magento ECG

Tags: magento2, coding-standards, magento-ecg

I am using the `base64_decode()` and `base64_encode()` in my code but `PHPCS` says

`The use of function base64_decode() is discouraged` so what's the equivalence of this core PHP function in Magento2?

Comment: There is literally no wrapper class for this function, closest you can go is \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize which json decode and base_64decode the string simultaneously, classic case of Magento being Magento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento does not have equivalence function of `base64_decode() and base64_encode()` method.

Using `phpcs:ignore` you can use these two methods.Like Below

```
// phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
    base64_decode($content);
// phpcs:ignore Magento2.Security.LanguageConstruct.ExitUsage
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, does magento marketplace accept this code in extension?

Comment: yes, they will accept the extension so far my understanding.

Comment: Sir, please look on this issue : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317446/magento-2-getting-error-inside-tracking-shipment-popup

Comment: As seen in /vendor/magento files, we only need the first ignore    
`// phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction  
    base64_decode($content);`      
.      <br />
The second ignore      
  
`// phpcs:ignore Magento2.Security.LanguageConstruct.ExitUsage`    
  
Is used when the PHP command "exit" is used

Answer (score 2):

Both the method have different Interface.

**Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface.php** used for encode URL.

**Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface.php** used for decode URL.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\DecoderInterface $urlDecoder
) {
    $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
    $this->urlDecoder = $urlDecoder;
}

public function execute()
{
  //base64_encode()
  $this->urlEncoder->encode($Url);

  //base64_decode()
  $this->urlDecoder->decode($UrlEncoded);
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for general-purpose wrapper method. Those are for URLs specifically.

Comment: Yes It provides a method to encode the URL provided to it into a base64 format.
For Reference -https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/framework/url-library.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   //@codingStandardsIgnoreStart
     base64_decode($data);
   //@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer about `EncoderInterface` and `DecoderInterface` is good but I wasn't happy having this as two separated properties to use.

Doing a little bit more digging I found out that `Magento\Framework\Url\Decoder` is setting the URL result to urlBuilder as `sessionUrlVar` which is not always intended and I definitely wasn't happy about.

I was looking for something I can pass safely as URL param for secure file download (verification permission to the file etc) so I wanted to encode file ID and customer ID in the URL param. I also wanted the function not to affect any other URL building or anything else so I found this class:

`Magento\Framework\Encryption\UrlCoder`

Usage is same as with any other encryptor, which in my case looked like (input/output is flat array with named keys):

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Service\Encoder;

use Magento\Framework\Encryption\UrlCoder;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class FileDownloadUrlParam
{

    public function __construct(
        private readonly Json $jsonSerializer,
        private readonly UrlCoder $urlCoder
    ) {
    }

    public function encode(array $attributes): string
    {
        return $this->urlCoder->encode(
            $this->jsonSerializer->serialize($attributes)
        );
    }

    public function decode(string $param): array
    {
        return $this->jsonSerializer->unserialize(
            $this->urlCoder->decode($param)
        );
    }
}
```

As this is PHP 8.1, it's like this, for PHP 8.2 project I would make whole class as readonly instead of it's properties. I stripped the code above by any documentation comments to keep it shorter but any IDE should autogenerate it from function definitions. Also I rely on throwing exception from any of the used encoders and serializers, to be passed to the caller, so exception handler should be IMHO elsewhere - hence it's not here.

Also if someone tries to decode it, it's totally fine as there will be just two IDs which wouldn't tell anything.